# Girsanov's theorem and likelihood for random initial conditions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider as an example the Stochastic Differential Equation
$$
   \text{d}Y(t) = -\kappa Y(t) \text{d}t + \sigma \text{d} B(t),  \qquad t \geq 0
$$

where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, $\kappa$ and $\sigma$ are
positive constants. If $Y(0) = 0$, Girsanov's theorem tells that the
distribution of the process $Y(t)$ is absolutely continuous
w.r.t. that of a standard Brownian. If $\sigma$ is known, this theorem
defines a likelihood function for an (ideal) continuously observed
path $t \in [0, \, T]$ with $T >0$.  A maximum
likelihood estimator for $\kappa$ can be consequently be derived as
described by [Phillips and
Yu](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.852.120&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Now assume that $Y(t)$ is stationary, which implies that $Y(0)$ is
centred normal with variance $\sigma^2/(2 \kappa)$. Can we still then
use Girsanov's theorem to define a likelihood function? If yes, what
relations exist between this *infill* or *continuous record*
likelihood and the simply defined likelihood function arising from
partial observations $Y(t_i)$ when the instants $t_i$ tend to fill the
fixed interval $[0,\,T]$?

More generally how can we cope with random initial conditions for a
continuously observed process having a state-space representation?  As
a major difference with the example above, the initial state will no
longer be observed.